# How return items from a custom spider middleware

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware

I've created my Custom SpiderMiddleware from OffsiteMiddleware. A simple copy and paste from the original class, maybe it exist a better method.

I would collect the filtered offsite domains.
My pipeline works.

But i don't know how return the items to my pipeline.

Thanks for your help.

```
def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
    items = []
    for x in result:
        if isinstance(x, Request):
            if x.dont_filter or self.should_follow(x, spider):
                yield x
            else:
                domain = urlparse_cached(x).hostname
                if domain and domain not in self.domains_seen[spider]:
                    self.domains_seen[spider].add(domain)
                    # ***My items ===> items.append(OutboundsLinks(url = domain))***
        else:
            yield x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**process_spider_output() must return an iterable of Request or Item objects.**

```
def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
    items = []
    for x in result:
        if isinstance(x, Request):
            if x.dont_filter or self.should_follow(x, spider):
                yield x
            else:
                domain = urlparse_cached(x).hostname
                if domain and domain not in self.domains_seen[spider]:
                    self.domains_seen[spider].add(domain)
                    # create an item here and yield it 
        else:
            yield x
```

Comment: Hi, It works thank for your help. I've just yield an BaseItem, not a list like in my code. I'm noob in python and i don't very understand the difference return vs yield.Is there a better solution than my code for the same result ?